# Python JSON to XML conversion without json2xml library

Tags: python, json, xml

I am just getting started with Python and I am trying to convert a JSON file to XML. I have looked at lots of tutorials and messed about with the code but I am stuck. Here is a snippet of the JSON file:

```
{
    "students":[
    {"id":897654,
        "fullName":{
            "title":"Mrs",
            "first":"Lisa",
            "surname":"Penny",
            "other":["Melanie"]},
        "age": 32,
        "city": "London"},

    {"id":786789,
        "fullName":{
            "title":"Mr",
            "first":"Lorenzo",
            "surname":"Dubois",
            "other":["Ruelle", "Garlen"]},
        "age": 38,
        "city": "Paris"},
```

And here is the code I am working with:

```
with open('People.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = js.load(json_file)

root = et.Element('students')

_id = et.SubElement(root, 'id').text = data['students']['id']
```

I get the error:
list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['students']` is a list, whose *elements* are dictionaries with an `id` key; `data['students']` itself has no such key.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for my ignorance but how do I access the elements then? All of the tutorials I looked at just chained the keys

Comment: The same way you get the elements of any list.